# Kannel and receive SMS from other SMPP to my system

Tags: sms, smpp, kannel

I'm using kannel SMPP (kannel.org) and for me need more information how to receive SMS messages from other SMPP server.

I know, for me need to add to kannel config this:

```
group = sms-service
keyword =
keyword-regex = .*
catch-all = yes
max-messages = 0
get-url = "http://website/sms.php?sender=%p&text=%a"
```

I need to add user for SMS pull'ing, but found only this example:

```
group = sendsms-user
username = ***************
password = hard2guess
concatenation= true
max-messages = 10000
```

But here is for sending SMS user, not for pull'ing.

Can somebody tell me more about how to create account for other SMPP server and receive SMS messages from other SMPP server?

Comment: you have to buy a sms gateway.

Comment: We are SMS provaiders, for me need more information how add SMS from our client bny SMPP and KANNEL. I don't know how to make account for our clients for SMS pull'ing to our system over SMPP.

Comment: Hi Markas - please install openSMPPBox which is in kannels/addons folder. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SMPP account adding SMPP information is easy all you need is add a new `SMPP` `group`

Sample SMPP Configuration (Transceiver Mode)

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
system-type=
smsc-username = user
smsc-password = pass
host = x.x.x.x
port = 10000
transceiver-mode = true
my-number = 123456
interface-version = 34
source-addr-ton = 0
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
enquire-link-interval = 60
reconnect-delay = 60
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc.log"
log-level = 1
```

I hope thi shelps

Thanks

:)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to allow a client to connect to you on SMPP and send messages via your system. If this is correct then you need to be a SMPP SMSC and currently your kannel is only acting as an  [ESME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESME) .

To get Kannel to act as a SMSC you need to install a version of SMPP which will act as a **SMSC** and allow clients to connect to send a message. Because Kannel doesn't have this built in you can try installing the open source software called **OpenSMPPBox**

OpenSMPPBox is included in the Addons folder of the latest Kannel development release (version 1.5.0). You'll need to install this via SVN to get the code and then compile this on your machine to get OpenSMPPBox up and running. You have to also download the latest version of kannel's source code in order to compile OpenSMPPBox.

Once you have installed OpenSMPPBox it connects to Kannel's Bearerbox and operates as a way to allow clients to connect to you on SMPP and then route messages straight to Kannel. When it is running you can set a username and password for a client and give them your server IP to connect.

There's a [Manual for OpenSMPPBox](http://www.chimit.nl/kannel/userguide.pdf) which will help with the installation and configuration.

Comment: How come my comment got voted down? Baba's comment above specifically doesn't answer the question the user has asked. The user wants to allow someone else to connect to his kannel, not for his kannel to connect to an SMSC. My answer gives the details of how Markas can do this.

Comment: "It sounds like you want to allow a client to connect to you on SMPP and send messages via your system". No. He just want to receive and send SMS from his system, so just adding **host**, **port**, **type** ... like Baba hinted.

Answer (score 0):

one very important thing that you might need to verify from your SMPP provider is the version they are running on. If the version is lower than 3.4, then you will be required to switch off the transceiver-mode by commenting it out from your kannel.conf file. Failure to do this will result into an endless loop of Kannel trying to connect to the SMPP without any success.

Best of luck.